# How acces to object id with button Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I made a crud, but i don't know how to access to the object ID when i clicked the buttons edit / x (delete)

the event.target return the edit / x buttons values

have this in my html template

```
<div>     
     <input type="text" name="Memo title"  placeholder="Write here your MEMO" 
     maxlength="27" v-model="writeMemo">
 
     <textarea cols="25" rows="5" maxlength="280" v-model="writeMemoBody"> 
     </textarea>                           
</div>
<button @click="createMemit">MEM-it</button>

--------------------------------etc-----------------------------------------------------
<div v-for="(memit) in memits" :key='memit.id' class="mem-it">
     <div>
          <h3>{{ memit.title }}</h3> 
          <p>{{ memit.body }}</p>
          <button @click="editMemit">Edit</button>
          <button @click.capture="deleteMemit($event)">X</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

and this is the way to create a "memit"

```
data(){
        return{
            writeMemo: "",
            writeMemoBody: "",
            memits: [],
             
        }
    },
methods: {

        createMemit() {
            this.memits.push({
                id: Math.random(),
                title:this.writeMemo,
                body:this.writeMemoBody
            });
            this.writeMemo='';
            this.writeMemoBody='';
            localStorage.setItem('old-memits',JSON.stringify(this.memits));              
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call it like this

```
<button @click="editMemit(memit.id)">Edit</button>
```